# Save DOM node and it's event handlers in the backend

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery-clone

I am trying to make a page which consists of many UI tools and visualizations. The problem is as these visualizations increase in a single page the performance of the browser goes down and becomes slower.

I was thinking that if I can save some UI nodes which user is not looking at and send it to server for saving and when users tries to come to the same node to visualize I can get the node and it's event handlers and initialize it again faster.

I tried jquery clone method but when I stringify the object to save it looses the event handlers. Has anyone tried to do this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if i get the question right, but i assume that there is one scrollable page with lots of graphs and other visualizations. And problem is that page becomes too slow because of that (scrolling interacting, memory etc.). Have you tried to show user those visualizations only if they are in browser view and remove those which are not visible (including events). IF user scrolls back, it would get re-rendered once again (with initing events for this specific visualization).

Hope this helps if it not possible solution let me know i will remove this answer

Comment: Think like there are many tabs in a single page. I render those tabs when a user clicks on them, lets say user clicks on 15 tabs while exploring so UI will keep making DOM nodes and event handler for 15 of them, so it will increase the memory usage. Now when user going to 16th tab then memory usage is very high and rendering of new tab takes a lot of time, So I tried to hide other tabs keeping DOM in memory but it is still the memory consumption, I was thinking that if I can save the DOM form browsers memory to server side and bring it back again then it will solve the memory issues.

Comment: Saving DOM into server would not help because if it gets removed from client and and you somehow "temporary save it on server" and serve it later it would need same resources as before. I would remove unnecessary (not visible) DOM elements which would remove events for those elements, put down memory usage etc. And show them on clicking tab again or becoming visible again. I am not sure what stack you are using but if you have perforamnce problems with current visual maybe its time to switch to else.. for instance migrate from Jquery to react/vue etc. which would help improve performance